# Centering block view

Tags: views, blocks

Hello Drupal community!

I have a questions about displaying content with views. Is it possible to center the content within the block, in-browser?

Right now I have two entities next to each other, both left-aligned. I am trying to get them both centered in the block, and centered on the page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to right click and inspect the elements and find the div **class** or **id** that belongs to those blocks or fields.

Then with CSS you can center them. See [CENTERING THINGS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html). So just add the css to your theme's style.css file, located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder.

Then remember to flush the cache to see the changes.

---

**If you want to do it within Views using REWRITE RESULTS**

[image]

put `<center>[title]</center>`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I know I am able to go into the files and change the css, but is it possible, in drupal, in the browser, to alter the position??

Comment: @jill no, any positioning you see on any site is done with CSS or jQuery mainly. Although., you could use html `<center>` in your View if you REWRITE results of your field, using the replacement pattern. ex: `<center>[field_example]</center>`

Comment: @jill you can do it within views, see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Seems like a totally concrete answer to me - although somehow didn't work when I tried to implements :{

Comment: @jill is there a reason why you don't want to do it the css way?

Comment: well, I'm working on a website with other people, so all file changes need to go through a process (done locally, pushed, tested, merged)... but this issue needed a quick fix (although not very quick in the end lol...)

Comment: @NoSssweat Bootstrap was overriding custom css so I was having difficulty in centering the image. In my views under Rewrite Results, I put this <div><center>[replacement_token_name]</center></div> but I am not sure if it is the right way and why I cannot do it via css. I having similar problem with buttons.